# Algorithm vs algorithmic

Tags: adjectives, attributive-nouns

I encountered an expression *Improve my algorithm skills*. For me *algorithm skills* sounds unnatural and should be *algorithmic skills* or *become better at algorithms*. After short googling, I found few cases of using of the expression *algorithm skills*, but it was used sporadically and at the same time the expression *algorithmic skills* was used at the same articles. I didn't manage to find separate using of the expression *algorithm skills*.
The typical context in the articles was something like *Enhance Programming and Algorithm Skills* or *Improving your Algorithms and Data Structure Skills*, so it's not pure *algorithm skills* and I feel there's a different meaning.

Is it possible to say *my algorithm skills* without additional nouns and if it is, how natural is it?

Comment: I'd take algorithm skills to be about algorithms, and algorithmic skills to be about skills that hold an algorithmic quality to them, which makes less sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Algorithm skills" is a compound noun; it could have the fairly obvious meaning "skills in devising and using algorithms", which it most probably has in computer  science; it could also mean "skills that depend on certain algorithms", which is not likely, but you have to be someone in the field or someone who has got a fairly good idea of what programming involves in order to know or to suppose that. This is to say that for people not concerned closely enough with the term, it means more or less nothing; this is to say also that the term is endowed with a meaning only through the particular use that has been made of it in the field. Grammar has nothing to do with it and whether the pick of words reflects well the associated meaning depends on how familiar the coiners are with English. More precisely, it is to a certain point a matter of taste. The same goes for "algorithmic skills": the attribution  of meaning does not follow the principle for deducing the meaning of "red rose", for instance. As another instance, "yellow journalism" does not mean "journalism that is yellow". It follows that both terms have been defined (probably  informally) to mean the same thing (neglecting a possible added and less important meaning for "algorithmic skills"), that they are acceptable, and that the question  of which is best and which should prevail cannot be answered; possibly, both will be retained in the literature to come; just as well only one might remain current. Which *you* should use can only be decided by yourself.

The term  "Algorithms and Data Structure Skills" has nothing to  do with the purity of "algorithm skills". It  means very probably "Algorithms  (their study)  and  Data Structure Skills" because of the  plural (Algorithms). If a singular had been used ("Algorithm and Data Structure Skills") it  would  mean  "Algorithm Skills and Data Structure Skills"
(since "algorithm skills" is  a term of known definition).